# Append Values in NSSet To An Array of Type [String]

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I am attempting to get the values from an NSSet in core data and append those values to an array of type String.

```
func addStepsToArray() {
    if let steps = entity.steps {
        for i in steps {
            recipeStep.append(String(i))
        }
    }
}
```

`entity.steps` is the list of steps tied to a core data entity. This is an `NSSet`. I am trying to copy those values to an array of type String.

```
@State var recipeStep: [String]
```

When trying to do this in my for in loop, I receive the following error: `No exact matches in call to initializer`

If I remove the conversion of "I" to String, I receive the following error:

> Cannot convert value of type `NSSet.Element` (aka `Any`) to expected argument type `String`

Any idea on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSSet` is defined in Objective C, which didn't have generics. It's an untyped collection, so you don't statically know anything about its elements.

As you've noticed, your `i` variable isn't a `String`, it's an `Any`.

You're confusing type coercion ("casting") with type conversion. If `i` were a `Double`, you could call `String(i)` to invoke an initializer which takes a double, and processes into a String.

You tried something similar by calling `String(i)`, where you're making the Swift compiler find an initializer on `String` with the signitiure `init(_: Any)`.

There is no such initializer. And besides, that's not what you want. You don't want to create a new String from a different kind of value. You already have a string, it's just "hidden" behind an `Any` reference.

What you're looking for is to do a down-cast, from `Any` to `String`:

```
func addStepsToArray() {
    if let steps = entity.steps {
        for i in steps {
            guard let step = i as? String else {
                fatalError("Decide what to do if the value isn't a String.")
            }
            recipeStep.append(i as String)
        }
    }
}
```

I'll warn you though, there are several issues/blemishes with this code:

1. You're using a `for` loop to do what is ultimately just a mapping operation
2. Your computation doesn't return its ouput, and instead indirectly achieves its goal through a side-effect on `recipeStep`
3. Your computation doesn't take a its input as a parameter, and instead indirectly achieves its goal through a side-effect on `entity`
4. `i` is conventionally expected to be an integer index of a `for` loop iterating over a sequence of numbers. Here it's an `Any` (a String at runtime)

Here's what I would suggest instead:

```
func getRecipeSteps(from entity: MyEntityType) -> [String] {
    guard let steps = entity.steps else { return [] }

    return steps.map { step in
        guard let stringStep = step as? String else { 
            fatalError("Decide what to do if the value isn't a String.")
        }

        return step
    }
}
```

Then in the rest of your code (and your tests), you can write `self.recipeSteps = getRecipeSteps(from: myEntity)`. Elegant!

If you're certain that these `entity.steps` values can only ever be strings, then you can boil this down to a single `map` with a force-cast:

```
func getRecipeSteps(from entity: MyEntityType) -> [String] {
    entity.steps?.map { $0 as! String } ?? []
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the extremely detailed answer. I have tried all three approaches, but unfortunately the app crashes when landing on the page where the function executes (I am executing via .onAppear). The error is as follows: "Could not cast value of type 'RecipeTracker.StepsEntity' to 'NSString'". It looks like it is having trouble with the type casting. Thoughts?

Comment: Well you were operating on a misapprehension. You have some kind of `StepsEntity` which is clearly not a String.

Comment: StepsEntity itself is an entity that contains multiple attributes, but each step attribute within that entity is a String. Maybe if I tried something like entity.steps?.allObjects as? [StepsEntity]) and incorporated that into a map and it would return the correct data. I will give this a try later. I think the issue is it is trying to return all attributes in the entity, when it should only be returning the step attribute.

Comment: @nickreps So you probably want `entity.steps.map { step in steps.theStringValueYouWant }`. You haven't provided enough details in your question.

Comment: I ended up getting it to work using the following: func addSteps() {
        if let recipeSteps = (entity.steps?.allObjects as? [StepsEntity])?.sorted(by: { $0.stepNumber < $1.stepNumber }) {
            for index in recipeSteps {
                recipeStep.append(index.step ?? "")
                stepNumber.append(Int(index.stepNumber))
                                                                                                                                                  I am still going to mark yours as the accepted answer, as yours is correct based on what I described.

Comment: @nickreps comments don't support multiple lines, so code becomes a total mess. That code... could really use some work. I don't think you quite grasped the concepts I mentioned

Comment: I am currently modifying the code to translate it into something more efficient. The for in loop was the simplest way I could test to make sure it works (in a format that I am familiar with). Map is fairly new to me, but you provided me with enough to work with to make the implementation happen. Hopefully will have a map version completed shortly. Is there something better than map to replace a for in loop? Or is map still the way to go?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234592/discussion-between-alexander-and-nickreps).

Answer (score 0):

Just convert directly：

```
let set = Set(["1", "2", "3"])
let array = Array(set)
DDLog(set)//Set<String>)
DDLog(array)//[String]
```